# Cambiar color cuando cambie el input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero cambiar el color de un `input` de la siguiente manera:

- cuando valga 1 se debe dibujar en verde.
- cuando valga F se debe
  dibujar en rojo.

Hasta ahora sólo lo hace una vez pero lo debería hacer cuantas veces los cambie.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table :input').blur(function(){
       var $input = $(this);
       if($input.val() === 'F'){
          $input.addClass('rojo'); 
       } else {
           $input.addClass('verde');
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.rojo {
    background: red;
}
.verde {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
           <table class="tabla">
               <tr bgcolor="#085584ff">
                   <th width="100">Placa</th>
                   <th><input type="text" value="F"></th>
                   <th><input type="text" value="1"></th>
               </tr>
           </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

No se cómo hacer esto, si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería mucho, además lo logro en el evento `blur` y la idea es cuando cambie el `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo necesitas usar el evento `change` junto a blur, de este modo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table :input').on('blur change', function(){
       var $input = $(this);
       if($input.val() === 'F'){
          $input.addClass('rojo'); 
          $input.removeClass('verde');
       } else {
          $input.addClass('verde');
          $input.removeClass('rojo');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Aun sigue funcionando igual

Comment: Hola @Rimuru Tempest, me sirvio tu ayuda, solo que hizo falta remover la clase anterior por que lo que asi asi era concatenar clases y clases y solo funcionaba una vez

Comment: @sebastianvalencia es verdad, lo siento por no haber prestado atención a ese detalle.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es que se añaden dos clases a la vez que cambian la misma propiedad. Es por eso que no vuelve a cambiar el color, porque se queda con el que se le añadió primero.

En lugar de utilizar `$input.addClass()` podrías utilizar `$input.style['background']='red/green'`.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es asegurar que si vale 'F', el input no tenga la clase 'verde' y, cuando valga '1', el input no tenga la clase 'rojo', con `$input.classList.remove('verde/rojo')` respectivamente.

Comment: Gracias Octavio, pero tampoco funcionó